# error C3121: cannot change GUID for class 'IFilter'

Tags: c++, dll, namespaces

I'm using VS2012 and C++.
This error occurs in a .tlh file.
I checked the header files, and found `#import "C:\\Windows\\system32\\abc.dll" no_namespace`  in the beginning.
At first, I made this line as comment, there is no C3121 errors,however the #define variables can't be found.Error shown like this: `error C2065:undeclared identifier`.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most likely you have a collision with SDK defined `IFilter`. To rule that out, `#import` using a non-empty namespace.

Comment: @RomanR. Thanks for your reply. But what do you mean by using a non-empty namespace? What should I do?

Comment: Don't use `no_namespace`. You will have some namespace created for you. Or alternatively, specify desired namespace explicitly using [`rename_namespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t265fx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @RomanR. I changed the `no_namespace` to `rename_namespace("SL")`. And then add `using namespace SL;` in the cpp file. However, there is an error shows that SL is not a namespace.